polynomial $f$ having $n$ distinct roots implies either $f(x)\neq 0$ or $\deg f\geq n$
This is about two different results I have read in the note, where it says

Theorem 5. If $f(x)\in F[x]$ has distinct roots $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_n$, then $f(x)$ is divisible
by $(x − a_1)(x − a_2) · · · (x − a_n)$. In particular, either $f(x) \neq 0$ or $\deg f(x) \geq n$.


Corollary 6. A nonzero polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ of degree $n$ cannot have more than
$n$ distinct roots.

In Theorem 5, the author has not provided the proof of the last sentence. I suspect that it is a typo, since it should have been $f(x)=0$ or $\deg f(x)\geq n$, i,e.
$$f(x) \text{ is divisible by } (x − a_1)(x − a_2) · · · (x − a_n) \implies f(x)=0 ~\vee~ \deg f(x)\geq n$$
In that case, the proof would have then been:

Suppose that $f(x)$ divisible by $g(x):=(x − a_1)(x − a_2) · · · (x − a_n)$, and suppose $f(x)\neq 0$. Then $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ for some polynomial $h$. Then $\deg f=n+\deg h\geq n$.

Am I right that it is an error that $f(x)\neq 0$ in Theorem 5?
I would also like to know how to prove Corollary 6. Here is what I think:

Suppose $f$ is a non-zero polynomial of degree $n$. Assume that $f$ has, say, $p$ distinct roots. Then, by Theorem 5, we have $n\geq p$. This means that the number of roots of $f$ is at most $n$, i.e. $f$ can not have more than $n$ distinct roots.

I feel the proofs are correct, but I would like to know what you think.

Yes, the statement is incorrect as written. The conclusion is that either the degree of $f$ is at least $n$, or that $f$ is equal to the zero polynomial, not that it is different from $0$.

@ArturoMagidin Ok, thanks, good to know. If you have time, what do you think of my proofs (in particular Corollary)?
